# How to add date with foreign key from Create function Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have `product` table and `product_category` table.

I add new product as:

```
$product = Product::create($data);
```

After try to add category for this added product:

```
$category = new ProductCategoryItem();
        $category->category_id = $request->parent_id;
        $category->product_id = $product->id;
        $category->save();
```

But it gives me SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: What do you get if you `dd()` the `$request->parent_id` and the `$product->id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `eloquent` there is no need to manually handle the pivot table. If you set your relationships up correctly, you can use the `attach` or `sync` methods instead:

In Product:

```
public function categoryItems(){
  // use withTimestamps if you have timestamps in your pivot table
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\CategoryItem')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In CategoryItem:

```
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

In your Product controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $product = Product::create($request->all());
  // Assumes you have an array input in your form called 'categories'
  $product->categoryItems()->attach($request->input('categories'))
}
```

Comment: But if I have only two tables: product, product_images? And need to add images?

Comment: I mean in this case when I have method in Product model: `public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\ProductImage");
    }`

Comment: Is that a `many-to-many` relationship? Can one product have many images and an image belongToMany products or is it a `one to many`, a product can have many images but an image can belongTo one product?

Comment: Product can has one or more images (one to many). I tried this: `$product->images()->insert(UploadFiles::$files);`

Comment: I does not work because when I do insert array, there is not primary key `product_id` from `$product`

Comment: So, `product_id` is foreign key in table `product_image`

Comment: The foloowing works, but I need to add `product_id` in inserting array: `$product->images()->save(new ProductImage(UploadFiles::$files));`

Comment: But I need that tables will be connected automaticly

Comment: Yes, I posted that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202421/how-to-insert-in-laravel