# How to insert in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have output object `$product` after inserting data into table `Product`:

```
$product = Product::create($data);
```

In model `Product` I have:

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\ProductImage");
    }
```

The I try to add images to table `product_images`:

```
$product->images()->save(new ProductImage(UploadFiles::$files));
```

Relationship beetwen tables is `product.id = product_images`.

So, after inserting I get message:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `product_images` (`product_id`) values (21))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, firstly let's deal with saving one image:

Assuming you have a `product_images` table with `id`, `image`, `product_id`, you would attach an image like so:

```
$image = new ProductImage(['image' => 'myImage.jpg']);
$product->images()->save($image);
```

Now it looks like you have an array, so you can't save that directly, you need to put it in a for loop. I don't know the format of your `UploadFiles::$files`, but I'll assume it's just a list of file names to save:

```
$files = UploadFiles::$files;

foreach($files as $file){
  $image = new ProductImage(['image' => $file]);
  $product->images()->save($image);
}
```

Alternatively, you could create the whole thing as an array and use `saveMany`, which would be better:

```
$files = UploadFiles::$files;
$productImages = [];

foreach($files as $image){
  $productImages[] = new ProductImage(['image' => $image]);
}

$product->images()->saveMany($productImages);
```

Comment: `UploadFiles::$files` is array with one field `"image" => "path"`

Comment: Well, that error says that it can't find the image field. Have you added it to your `$fillable` array on the `ProductImage` model?